# Loop through tuple inside template returns null values

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to parse a tuple to a template, but I'm getting problems in loop through the tuple inside the template. I just get null values. I want to do this to use django pagination, which requires an object that can be looped.

This is my view where I create my tuple

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        print "login"
        user = request.user
        prods = Product.objects.all()

        i = 0
        print 'numero de produtos ' + str(len(prods))
        prodmatrix = {}
        for prod in prods:
            #                       0             1           2    3
            prodmatrix[str(i)] = [[prod.name], [prod.image], [], [prod.slug]] 
            reviews = Review.objects.filter(product=prod.id) #   ^ this is for tags
            print str(len(reviews))
            if len(reviews) != 0: 
                for review in reviews:
                    rev_alltags = review.tag.all()
                    for tags in rev_alltags[:3]:     #                           
                        print tags.name
                        prodmatrix[str(i)][2].append(tags.name) # append only tags 
            print str(i)
            i = i + 1
        #prodmatrix = tuple(prodmatrix)
        paginator = Paginator(prodmatrix.items(), 2)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            prodmatrix = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            prodmatrix = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            prodmatrix = paginator.page(paginator.num_page)
        return render(request, 'home.html',{'prodmatrix':prodmatrix})
```

And this is how I'm trying to loop thought the tuple in the template:

```
 {% for keys, values in prodmatrix %}
<li class="span3">
                                                    <div class="product-box">
{{ values.0.0 }} {{ values.0.3 }} {{ values.1.1 }} {{ values.1.2 }}
</div>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother converting the dict to a tuple.  Call the `items` method on the dict in order to get something you can iterate over in that way:

```
{% for keys, values in prodmatrix.items %}
  <li class="span3">
    <div class="product-box">
      {{ values.0.0 }} {{ values.0.3 }} {{ values.1.1 }} {{ values.1.2 }}
    </div>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

By the way, it might be simpler to do something like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # ...
    @property
    def tags(self):
        return self.review_set.values_list('tag_set__name', flat=True).distinct()


def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        products = Product.objects.prefetch_related('review_set__tag_set')
        return render(request, 'home.html', {
            'products': products,
        })
```

Then your template would look something like this:

```
{% for product in products %}
  <li class="span3">
    <img src="{{ product.image.image.url }}"/>
    <div class="product-box">
      {{ product.name }} -
      {{ product.tags|join:', ' }} -
      {{ product.slug }}
    </div>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I wanted to do this becuase I was trying to use django pagination, which required an object that can be looped

Answer (score 2):

Calling `tuple` on a dict just returns a tuple of the keys. I'm not quite sure why you're doing that but removing that line will probably work.

Comment: I wanted to do this becuase I was trying to use django pagination, which required an object that can be looped